# NVIDIA cuda enabled docker container issue - UserWarning: CUDA initialization: Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount()

Tags: docker, ubuntu, pytorch, nvidia-docker

I am trying to use the base images provided by NVIDIA that let us use their GPUs via Docker containers. Because I am using docker, there is no need for me to have CUDA Toolkit or CuDNN on my system. All I need to have is the right driver - which I have.

I can run the official pytorch docker containers and the containers utilize my GPU. However when I run anything using the base images from NVIDIA then I get the following Warning -

```
$ docker run --gpus all -it --rm -p 8000:8000 ubuntu-cuda-gpu:latest
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: Unexpected error from cudaGetDeviceCount(). Did you run some cuda functions before calling NumCudaDevices() that might have already set an error? Error 804: forward compatibility was attempted on non supported HW (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

The application executes, it just uses CPU. But I want to be able to use my GPU like I can when I run the same code(it is a simple pytorch example) using official pytorch docker images.

The [base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags/?page=1&ordering=last_updated) used is -

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04
# Setup
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y bash \
                   build-essential \
                   git \
                   curl \
                   ca-certificates \
                   python3 \
                   python3-pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists

# Your stuff
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir \
    torch \
    transformers \
...
```

If I just run the image without any machine learning code and try to execute nvidia-smi then I get the output as -

```
$ docker run --gpus all -it --rm -p 8000:8000 ubuntu-cuda-gpu:latest nvidia-smi
```

```
Sat Jun 12 19:15:21 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.80       Driver Version: 460.80       CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   31C    P8     9W / 170W |     14MiB / 12053MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This leads me to believe that at least something is right. But why is it that I am not able to use my GPU and how to make sure that I can?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: CUDA 11.3.x [requires](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#title-new-features) a 465.19.01 or newer driver.  The container you attempted to start with attempted to use a forward compatibility library to allow it to work anyway with your 460.xx driver but that didn't work because forward compatibility is not supported on your GeForce GPU.  The easiest solution might be to install the latest driver (in the base machine) for your GPU that is 465.xx or newer.  Alternatively you could modify your container to use cuda-11.2.x instead of cuda-11.3.x

Comment: @RobertCrovella you are right. After taking care of the compatibility issues I was able to get it working. You can add this as an answer, I will accept it.